# TypeScript - Union type from properties decorated with a specific decorator

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a generic type, which accepts a class, some of whose properties are decorated with a specific decorator, and create a type out of them

```js
class Image {
  @Attribute()
  public id: number;

  @Attribute()
  public src: string;

  public alt: string;
}

// ?? Should result in "id", "src"
type ImageAttributes = ExtractAttributes<typeof Image>
```

Comment: No, there's nothing to inherit here, I just want features to be applied to specific properties, similar to how column annotation works in ORMs like TypeORM

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no type indication that a field has been decorated. The [open issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) on that are almost as old as TS.

So, as of today, no.